# Grails Control javascript location using resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have added new Javascript library to the “ApplicationResources”:

```
jquerymobile{
    resource url:'css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css'
    resource url:'js/jquery.mobile/jquery.js'
    resource url:'js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js'
}
```

Than I used this library in the main.gsp:

```
    <g:javascript library="jquerymobile"/>

    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>      
    <g:layoutBody/>     
    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
    <g:javascript library="application"/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</body>
```

The result HTML was that grails concatenates both js files into one and place the script tag at the end.

```
.
.
.    
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">Loading&hellip;</div>

    <script src="/Tiv2/static/bundle-bundle_jquerymobile_defer.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <script src="/Tiv2/static/js/application.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

This causes bad behavior in the page. When clicking a link, I can see that the address bar in the browser get changed but page is not refreshing and stay on the current page where the link was clicked.
Only after manually refreshing the page (F5), browser load the linked page.

I tried using regular  tags and all worked ok.
How do I prevent Grails from combining js files into one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the exclude argument when declaring your resources so the bundle mapper doesn't run.

```
jquerymobile{
    resource url:'css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css', exclude: 'bundle'
    resource url:'js/jquery.mobile/jquery.js', exclude: 'bundle'
    resource url:'js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js', exclude: 'bundle'
}
```

The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html) covers this and is quite good. You should always start there.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
jquerymobile{
    defaultBundle false
    resource url:'css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css'
    resource url:'js/jquery.mobile/jquery.js'
    resource url:'js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js'
}
```

This will disable bundling for all resources in this module